How to configure LTSpice simulation to have current source add to circuit node rather than regulate it
sorry it is hard to word this question. I want to simulate a photodiode in this LTSpice simulation, but I know a current source will regulate the node to make sure the current going through it is whatever I set the current source value to. What I want to do instead is make it so it adds the current. So if the current source is set to 1 Amp and 1 Amp is coming from the diode on the other branch, the current going into the + side of the op amp is 2 Amps. As it is right now, I do believe it will only be 1 Amp because the current source is regulating that.


Is your amplifier an ideal one with infinite input impedance? If it is, where do you expect the current from I1 to go, except through the diode. If you want the source current and diode current to add, what path do you want the sum current to follow?

A current source does not 'regulate the current in a node'. It 'regulates the current through the current source'. That is, it will add current to the node it's connected to as you appear to require. Or at least it will do if you ground its other terminal, the simulation should error with that floating node.

Connect the current source like this: -

You don't need to ground the open terminal in a simulator when using an ideal current source.

Current sources need a path that starts at one terminal and terminates at its other terminal: (one cannot leave one of its terminal open-circuit). The current source that simulates photons must be positive in the schematic below. Photons can only cause diode anode to shift to a +ve voltage with respect to its cathode. In this case, the photon-generating current source supplies one microamp when light is on and zero current when light is off:

The generic "diode" model in LTspice is very simple. For a photodiode, you should at least add a few extra components, in addition to the current source that simulates photon input. The 100MEG resistor simulates a photodiode's real resistance. A dark photodiode should eventually rest with zero volts across its terminals - the 100MEG resistor ensures that.
Photodiodes often have large area, which means that their capacitance is significant. A guess for a small photodiode here is 5 picofarads.
LTspice requires a ground somewhere. In this example, one side of the photodiode is grounded - for a more complex circuit, the diode might not be directly grounded, but there should probably be a path to ground through other components.
